# react-router v6 history.location.search replacement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In `react-router` v5 I was able to use

```
let keyword = history.location.search
```

but in `react-router` v6 I get an error so what is the replacement for that code?

Edit: BTW I am not so good at router and currently converting a code from v5. I was wondering what should keyword return in v5? The path I am currently in?

Comment: Btw i defined location = useLocation() and imported the useLocation, But the problem is with history. I dont know how to define it

Comment: why do you need history then? use `location = useLocation()` or https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-search-params

Comment: @Mike i tried location.search and it is not returning anything

Comment: @Mike I am new to react router and i am following a course using v5 and i am using v6(I know that's dumb but i am half way throught) :p . I want to ask you what would history.location.search return in v5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's was ***always*** the case that you should have accessed the `search` value from the `location` object instead of the `history` object.

See [history is mutable](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history/history-is-mutable)

> The history object is mutable. Therefore it is recommended to access
> the `location` from the render props of `<Route>`, not from
> `history.location`. This ensures your assumptions about React are
> correct in lifecycle hooks.

If the tutorial is showing using `history.location.search` I wouldn't give it much weight.

In `react-router-dom@6` however, there are no longer any [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props), i.e. no `history`, `location`, or `match` props. You instead access these all via React hooks. Note that the `history` object is also no longer directly exposed out to components, replaced by a `navigate` function via the `useNavigate` hook.

To access the queryString RRDv6 introduced a new [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-search-params) hook.

Given URL `"/somepath?someQueryParam=123"`

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

const someQueryParam = searchParams.get("someQueryParam"); // 123
```

### Additional Question

> Edit: Btw I am not so good at router and currently converting a code
> from v5 I was wondering what should keyword return in v5 ? The path I
> am currently in?

`location.search` is a string, so you could process the string manually, or create a `URLSearchParams` object.

Check the RRDv5 [Query Parameters demo](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

They create a custom `useQueryHook`:

```
function useQuery() {
  const { search } = useLocation();

  return React.useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);
}
```

then access named query params with the getter:

```
let query = useQuery();

...

const name = query.get("name");
```

Comment: I tried to use searchParams and console.log(keyword) it is returning null in the console. and I have one more question the course i am following used sometimes  history.location.search and location.search but of what i understand both return a string value of the path but I am still confused what is the diffrence can you help please

Comment: @bysEcode Well, `searchParams.get("keyword")` only returns a non-null value of there's a `"keyword"` query parameter. I only used "keyword" since that is what your code was saving the search string as. You will OFC need to reference the query param when getting it. I've updated my answer to hopefully make this more clear. There's almost zero need to use `history.location` at all when you have the `location` object available. Like the link states, the `history` object is a mutable reference so there's no guarantee on its value with regards to the React component lifecycle.

Comment: lets say the url is ..../abc?keyword=4 / So you are saying instead of doing location.search.split('=')[1] , I can just use const keyword = searchParams.get("keyword")

Comment: @bysEcode Yes, exactly that. The first way you'd need to split on `"?"` or do `location.search.slice(1)` to get the rest of the search string minus the `"?"`, then split on `"&"` to get array of key-value strings, *then* split each on `"="` to get the key-value pairs. There's no real guarantee that the `"keyword"` would be the query param at a specific index either, so you wouldn't want to count on it being the first or any specific param.

Answer (score 1):

example url: `https://example.com/?foo=bar`

```js
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const Component = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams()
  const foo = searchParams.get('foo')
  console.log(foo) // "bar"
  return <></>
}
```

Obviously, you need to use this inside a router.

Note: all search param values are strings.

Comment: One question in this example https://asfaf.com/product?foo=bar , what would location.search returns ? 'product?foo=bar' or 'foo=bar' ? please help me here

Comment: It would return `?foo=bar`. It returns everything that's between `?` and `#` (if there is one), including the question mark. Those are the search parameters of location.